Intall python package with pip, respecting current installation
I want to use a singularity container with jax preinstalled e.g. based on this image. On top of that, I want to install PyMC with numpyro, to get NUTS sampling with GPU acceleration.
My attempt is to use the def file
Bootstrap: docker
From: nvcr.io/nvidia/jax:23.04-py3

%post
    pip install pymc numpyro

%test
    python -c "import jax;print(jax.devices())"

The test fails, since the post-step uninstalls the local jax packages and installs a new version from PyPA. That is not acceptable, since the docker image comes with some very specific locally compiled jaxlib versions and the like.
Can I give some instructions to pip to "install these two packages, and select some version that is compatible with what is already installed"?

It seems my problem goes away when updating the base image to 24.08, but my question about pip still remains. I would love to be able to "install but only if you don't break things"

I think what you're looking for is pip install --no-deps.
See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#options for more information.
